# How do I add different datatypes in print function in R?

Tags: r

Like I want to output `The sum of two and three is: 5`,
Then how do I join in:
`

```
num1 <- 2
num2 <- 3

print("The sum of two and three is: ", num1 + num2..??
`
```

Answer (score 1):

We can either use `sprintf`

```
print(sprintf('The sum of two and three is: %d', num1 + num2))
#[1] "The sum of two and three is: 5"
```

Or  `paste` to concatenate two strings

```
print(paste0("The sum of two and three is: ", num1 + num2))
#[1] "The sum of two and three is: 5"
```

Or with `glue`

```
glue::glue("The sum of two and three is: {num1 + num2}")
#The sum of two and three is: 5
```

Comment: @DikeshShrestha Based on the input you showed, I get the output and I showed that output